# Passing data between activities without switching

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a project and I'd like to pass a number between 2 activities. BUT, I don't want to change activity automatically (using startIntent).
But if I don't use the startIntent, I can't pass my variable between the activities. 
Hope you could help me ! Thanks !

Comment: Why would you need to send data to an Activity that you're not going to move to the foreground? Sounds like a Service might be what you really want to implement, but it's hard to say. You really ought to provide more information about the *actual* problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: You can use static variables